# Making Custom SRV for ROS2 service node return rosidl_generate_interface_error when build

Tags: python, ubuntu-22.04, ros2

### System Specifications:

```
Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
ROS2 HUMBLE
PYTHON 3.10
```

### Description of the problem faced

I am currently working on a project which requires me to build a ros2 service-client server which uses a custom message. I have created an package interface which include package.xml, CMakeLists.txt and srv and msg folder.

In the srv folder, there is an .srv file with this

```
bool input1
---
geometry_msgs/PoseStamped output1
```

In the msg folder, there is an .msg file

```
sensor_msgs/Imu msg1
```

My CMakeLists.txt files has

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(interfaces)

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
# uncomment the following section in order to fill in
# further dependencies manually.
# find_package(<dependency> REQUIRED)

find_package(geometry_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(sensor_msgs REQUIRED) 
find_package(rosidl_default_generators REQUIRED)

rosidl_generate_interfaces(${PROJECT_NAME}
  "srv/WifiGeo.srv"
  "msg/WifiData.msg"
  DEPENDENCIES geometry_msgs sensor_msgs)# Add packages that above messages depend on

if(BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
  # the following line skips the linter which checks for copyrights
  # comment the line when a copyright and license is added to all source files
  set(ament_cmake_copyright_FOUND TRUE)
  # the following line skips cpplint (only works in a git repo)
  # comment the line when this package is in a git repo and when
  # a copyright and license is added to all source files
  set(ament_cmake_cpplint_FOUND TRUE)
  ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()

ament_package()
```

My package.xml has

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://download.ros.org/schema/package_format3.xsd" schematypens="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"?>
<package format="3">
  <name>interfaces</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>Interface for topics and services</description>
  <maintainer email="email">nyongcyongs98</maintainer>
  <license>TODO: License declaration</license>

  <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake</buildtool_depend>
  
  <depend>geometry_msgs</depend>
  <depend>sensor_msgs</depend>

  <build_depend>rosidl_default_generators</build_depend>

  <exec_depend>rosidl_default_runtime</exec_depend>

  <member_of_group>rosidl_interface_packages</member_of_group>

  <test_depend>ament_lint_auto</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_lint_common</test_depend>

  <export>
    <build_type>ament_cmake</build_type>
  </export>
</package>
```

#### Problem

When I go back to the root workspace and run **colcon build**,
its return me this error

```
Starting >>> interfaces
Starting >>> rssi
--- stderr: interfaces                                                   
CMake Error at /opt/ros/humble/share/rosidl_adapter/cmake/rosidl_adapt_interfaces.cmake:42 (get_executable_path):
  Unknown CMake command "get_executable_path".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/humble/share/rosidl_cmake/cmake/rosidl_generate_interfaces.cmake:130 (rosidl_adapt_interfaces)
  CMakeLists.txt:18 (rosidl_generate_interfaces)


---
Failed   <<< interfaces [0.73s, exited with code 1]
Aborted  <<< rssi [0.75s]

Summary: 0 packages finished [1.14s]
  1 package failed: interfaces
  1 package aborted: rssi
  2 packages had stderr output: interfaces rssi
  1 package not processed
```

I have search online for quite awhile and no one else seems to face this error. I have a guess that perhaps rosidl_generate_interface has some functions that got deprecated. Did anyone face this problem recently? Thanks!!

---

Comment: what is your `cmake` version? I could build this package in my system. Maybe you have an outdated package

Comment: I also hope that your `email` in the `package.xml` is a valid one, otherwise it won't work

Comment: @ignacio I have updated my cmake to the latest version, 3.22 , and it still fails.

Comment: @ignacio my email is definitely a valid one

Comment: Ok i found out that my package is missing a include/interfaces folder, that why its fails
Thanks for your help!!

Comment: were you able to build the [custom msg/srv tutorial](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Custom-ROS2-Interfaces.html)?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! Was celebrating Chinese New Year. But yeah I was able to build the custom msg/srv tutorial. And it was from there that I was able to find out about the missing folder.
To add on I did face this error stackoverflow.com/questions/72752937/…, and was able to solve it by pip install lark && pip install empy

Comment: I faced this error while building kobuki_ros_interfaces again.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75229623/building-kobuki-ros-and-kobuki-interfaces-return-rosidl-generate-interfaces-erro

Comment: only now I saw your comment about the directory paths... Is this thread solved then?

Comment: Yes!! The main problem lies in a missing file that the author forgot to include and causes my ament_cmake to default to that package. Thanks alot !!