# Building kobuki_ros and kobuki_interfaces return rosidl_generate_interfaces error

Tags: python-3.x, cmake, ros2

### To replicate full error

#### Requirements

```
Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
ROS2 HUMBLE
PYTHON3
```

#### Installation/Setup guide

#### Installing pyenv:

https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/#virtual-environments-and-pyenv

**If python3 version is < 3.8,skip this step**

After you are done installing pyenv:

```
pyenv install -v 3.7.16
```

Each version of python installed will be located in pyenv directory

```
ls ~/.pyenv/versions
```

You can uninstall pythons by, don't do this

```
pyenv uninstall <version>
```

Check all python versions by

```
pyenv versions
```

For more information about the usage of pyenv, you can read the website from the link above. It provides a very detailed walkthrough pyenv

IF your python version is >3.8

Remember to source ros2

Make the workspace and localize python

```
mkdir turtlebot_ws && cd turtlebot_ws
pyenv local 3.7.16 #change local python for this folder
python -V
```

Output should be

```
Python 3.7.16
```

In this folder, download script to setup workspace for kobuki

```
#a virtual environment launcher that will fetch build tools from pypi (colcon, vcstools)
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kobuki-base/kobuki_documentation/release/1.0.x/resources/venv.bash || exit 1

#custom build configuration options for eigen, sophus
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kobuki-base/kobuki_documentation/release/1.0.x/resources/colcon.meta || exit 1

#list of repositories to git clone
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kobuki-base/kobuki_documentation/release/1.0.x/resources/kobuki_standalone.repos || exit 1
```

After that create a virtual env with this local python version

```
pyenv virtualenv 3.7.16 .venv
### pyenv virtualenv <versionname> <projectname>
```

Activate the virtual env

```
pyenv activate .venv
```

Then install kobuki from source

```
mkdir src

#vcs handles distributed fetching of repositories listed in a .repos file
vcs import ./src < kobuki_standalone.repos || exit 1
```

Now go into the src folder and delete ecl_lite, and clone in stonier version

```
cd src
rm -rf ecl_lite
git clone https://github.com/stonier/ecl_lite.git
```

Also clone in two other repo and one more dependencies

```
git clone https://github.com/kobuki-base/kobuki_ros_interfaces.git
git clone https://github.com/kobuki-base/kobuki_ros.git
pip install catkin_pkg lark empy
```

Now we can go back to root workspace and build

```
cd ..

# build everything
colcon build --merge-install --cmake-args -DBUILD_TESTING=OFF

# disable any unused cmake variable warnings (e.g. sophus doesn't use BUILD_TESTING)
colcon build --merge-install --cmake-args -DBUILD_TESTING=OFF --no-warn-unused-cli

# build a single package
colcon build --merge-install --packages-select kobuki_core --cmake-args -DBUILD_TESTING=OFF

# build everything, verbosely
VERBOSE=1 colcon build --merge-install --event-handlers console_direct+ --cmake-args -DBUILD_TESTING=OFF

# build release with debug symbols
colcon build --merge-install --cmake-args -DBUILD_TESTING=OFF -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo

Then update source workspace and deactivate venv
```

## update the source workspace

```
vcs pull ./src
source install/setup.bash
pyenv .venv deactivate
```

### Error

```
--- stderr: kobuki_ros_interfaces                                             
CMake Error at /opt/ros/humble/share/rosidl_adapter/cmake/rosidl_adapt_interfaces.cmake:42 (get_executable_path):
  Unknown CMake command "get_executable_path".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/humble/share/rosidl_cmake/cmake/rosidl_generate_interfaces.cmake:130 (rosidl_adapt_interfaces)
  CMakeLists.txt:55 (rosidl_generate_interfaces)


---
Failed   <<< kobuki_ros_interfaces [0.64s, exited with code 1]
Aborted  <<< ecl_eigen [0.05s]
Aborted  <<< ecl_config [0.07s]
Aborted  <<< ecl_mpl [0.07s]
Aborted  <<< ecl_command_line [0.07s]
```

I tried building kobuki_ros_interfaces alone and it works. It fails when I try to build everything together.

Comment: what is the actual error ?  where are you stuck ?

Comment: When i run colcon build --merge-install. But it has been fixed as shown in the answers and comments below. Thanks anws!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is verbose enough for you to understand what is wrong i.e.:

```
--- stderr: kobuki_ros_interfaces                                             
CMake Error at /opt/ros/humble/share/rosidl_adapter/cmake/rosidl_adapt_interfaces.cmake:42 (get_executable_path):
  Unknown CMake command "get_executable_path".
```

Judging by this the CMake file which is called from within the `[...]/rosidl_generate_interfaces.cmake` is calling a function named `get_executable_path`. You didn't share with us the `rosidl_adapt_interfaces.cmake` so I had to **google it**.

[Here is the link for the actual `.cmake` file that is causing the issues.](https://github.com/ros2/rosidl/blob/rolling/rosidl_adapter/cmake/rosidl_adapt_interfaces.cmake)

The lines that you should be interested in are lines 40-42:

```
  find_package(ament_cmake_core REQUIRED)  # for get_executable_path
  find_package(Python3 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Interpreter)
  get_executable_path(python_interpreter Python3::Interpreter CONFIGURE)
```

You are most likely missing the `ament_cmake_core` package that is required for the `get_executable_path` as the author of said `.cmake` file commented.

Try to get the missing package or make sure that the one that you use has the required function that is missing.